# Locking screen so the user must enter a pattern or PIN in Cordova

Tags: cordova, authentication, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, lockscreen

My wish is that when user opens the app, he must provide his fingerprint, pattern or PIN so the app can know it's really him (additional security).

I'm currently using "cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio" plugin and it works perfectly on iOS and Android devices who have fingerprint or FaceID enabled. Unfortunately this plugin doesn't work on devices which don't have the fingerprint enabled (or don't have the hardware for it), but they're using just a pattern or PIN or nothing at all.

I've also tried the "cordova-plugin-screen-locker" plugin but it doesn't seem to work at all (nothing happens on 'lock' or 'unlock').

My expectation is that if the user has fingerprint or FaceID enabled the app demands that but if he has a pattern or PIN enabled, it demands that. I was searching for a plugin that would show only pattern or PIN but I didn't manage to find it.

Does anyone know if such plugin already exists or do I need to write it by myself?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a solution at that time (except the one mentioned in the post) so I kinda put the app in the background for now as I don't have time to research further.
It works okay if user has FaceID or Fingerprint enabled but it fails if the user doesn't have any security enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such plugin public available. However, I suggest to adapt the "cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio" according to your needs.

For my purpose, I wanted to encrypt / decrypt some text after the user authenticates with Fingerprint or device credentials. I adapted the FingerprintAIO plugin so that it offers two methods:

`encrypt(alias, plainText)` → `encryptedText + initializationVector`

and

`decrpyt(alias, encryptedText, initializationVector)` → `plainText`

For Android, you cannot pass a CryptoObject to the BiometricPrompt, because pin/pattern/password authentication is not considered safe enough.
Instead, you show an authentication dialog to the user, and do your authentication/encryption within a given "validity duration" (e.g. 3 seconds) immediately after successful authentication according to this Android developer guide:

https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#biometric-or-lock-screen

Here are some relevant code snippets:

The BiometricPromt is created as follows

```
BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("My Title")
            .setDescription("Some description")
            .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
            .build();
biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
```

in the `onAuthenticationSucceeded` method of the `biometricPrompt` call for encryption:

```
KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias,
    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
    .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(VALIDITY_DURATION_IN_SECONDS)
    .build();
generateSecretKey(spec);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
byte[] initVector = cipher.getIV(); // part of the return value
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainInputText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

and for decryption:

```
SecretKey secretKey = getSecretKey(alias);
Cipher output = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
final GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, initVector); // initVector is a parameter of 'decrypt'
output.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, spec);
String decodedText = new String(output.doFinal(encrypted), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

For iOS I have not implemented the plugin yet

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the Cordova implementation does, but the Android API is BiometricPrompt with setDeviceCredentialAllowed. This was added to the framework in Q.

The behavior is also available through the androidx.biometric library versions beta01 and later.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric

Before invoking auth with setDeviceCredentialAllowed, you need to at a minimum check KeyguardManager#isDeviceSecure to check if a pin/pattern/password has been set.